# Django почему поиск по названию не работает

Tags: python, django

у меня есть модель Product, хранящая в себе информацию о продукте, я хочу реализовать поиск по названию данного продукта, но почему-то у меня ничего не получается (выводится страница без постов), в чём может быть проблема?

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('q')
    if search_query:
        paginator = Product.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_query))
    else:
        paginator = Product.objects.all()
    return page_object
```

**html**

```
<nav class="navbar-brand navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <form action="{% url 'product_search' %}" method="get" class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="q" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Поиск" aria-label="Search"
               required="">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Искать</button>
    </form>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

В коде вместо paginator нужно создать page_object, который возвращается из функции paginate_queryset и который вы должны использовать для отображения страницы.

Кроме того, в вашем коде не указан шаблон для отображения результатов поиска. + Нужно создать шаблон, который будет отображать результаты поиска.

views.py:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Product


def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('q')
    if search_query:
        product_list = Product.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_query))
    else:
        product_list = Product.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(product_list, 10)  # Пагинация: 10 элементов на странице

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_object = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'page_object': page_object, 'query': search_query})
```

search_results.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Результаты поиска</h1>
    {% if query %}
        <p>Результаты по запросу "{{ query }}":</p>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for product in page_object %}
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.title }}">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.title }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
                        <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Подробнее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            <p>По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if page_object.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page=1">&laquo; первая</a>
                <a href="?page={{ page_object.previous_page_number }}">&lsaquo; предыдущая</a>
            {% endif %}

            <span class="current-page">
                Страница {{ page_object.number }} из {{ page_object.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>

            {% if page_object.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ page_object.next_page_number }}">следующая &rsaquo;</a>
                <a href="?page={{ page_object.paginator.num_pages }}">последняя &raquo;</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: во-первых: данная функция не возвращает шаблон и словарь, потому что она,  наверное, будет использоваться на нескольких страницах, во-вторых: если даже полностью скопировать ваш код, то он тоже почему-то не работает (по запросу не было ничего найдено) хотя, вроде, всё правильно.